# Authentication problems with Spotipy

Tags: python, authentication, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to authenticate my Spotify account with the API through the Spotipy Python package. I have registered the redirect URI with my developer account. The code I am running is below:

```
#Import packages
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
from spotipy import oauth2
import sys
import os
import spotipy.util as util

#Set environment varialbes
os.environ["SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID"] = 'client id'
os.environ["SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET"] = 'secret id'
os.environ["SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI"]= 'localhost:8888/callback'
username='my username'

#Attempt to authenticate
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username)
```

I am taken to the Spotify login homepage where I am prompted to authorize my developer project to access my information, but when I click "Agree," I get redirected to a Spotify "Error" web page, instead of the page with the token. I've tried using different URIs and hard coding the environment variables to no avail. Does anyone know where I might be going wrong here?

Many thanks!

Comment: What error code and http status code are you getting when you get redirected back to your callback page?